QuickFix/n Multiple Connections
I have developed a trading terminal, which now needs to connect to the trading server using FIX Protocol.
There will be thousands of trading accounts demo as well as live.
I have created the config files:
ACCCEPTOR
SenderCompID=TSERVER
TargetCompID=TT
INITIATOR
SenderCompID=TT
TargetCompID=TSERVER
but problem is its allowing only one login from trading terminal to the trading server.
How can i achieve 100's of logins without entering them in config files with different SenderCompID's  ?

I'm not clear: Are you writing the clients AND the server?

yes both, just need to know how i can have multiple sessions with same Sender and Target CompID's , as i cant put all logins in config files manually and create unique comp ids

I think for that to work you need to construct sessions dynamically, but I don't know if quickfixn supports this.
